# Як перекласти "each and every"

Tags: from-english

Як перекласти "each and every".

Англомовні використовують *each* для окремих елементів у групі чи списку з двох чи більше елементів. Це часто схоже за значенням на *every*, але *every* використовується для покликання до групи або списку з трьох і більше елементів.

Я поки що придумав тільки **всяк і кожен**.

РЕД:
Хотілось би перекласти, наприклад, таке:

- *each and every time,*
- *each and every one,*
- *each and every day.*

Можуть бути інші варіанти, питання - загальне.

Comment: *Для всіх і кожного* — [3,000,000 посилань](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%96%D1%85+%D1%96+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Comment: Чи можете ви навести приклад в якому українському реченні ви бажаєте використати "each and every"?

Comment: Підтримую версію Vitaly Zubkov щодо підсилення сенсу слова "кожний". Each and every day можна в такому разі перекласти як "Кожного Божого дня", "each and every one" дещо кострубато як "буквально кожен з них". Щодо "each and every time" не маю версій.

Answer (score 5):

Пам'ятайте, що при перекладі не конче зберігається кількість слів.
Емоційне навантаження в українській мові часто [передається](http://linguistics.kspu.edu/webfm_send/1284) суфіксами, тож можна використати слово *[кожнісінький](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)*, що має значення «кожний без винятку».